# Skyrim Mac Mouse Simultaneous Click

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, macos, mouse

I recently picked Skyrim on my Mac and I can't double cast or bash with my shield, because those actions require a simultaneous click. Sometimes I'm able to do it (don't ask me how), but I'm looking for a way to either map M2's functions to the keyboard OR find a way to properly configure my mouse in order to make the movements possible.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: To clarify: you're okay having to use a keyboard key to block?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from changing the button from controls?

Comment: From a past experience on a mouse that did not recognize simultaneous press. Try clicking/hold RB then immediately click the LB and then release.

Comment: @ColinD The problem isn't that the mouse doesn't recognise both, it's that the mouse is physically incapable of being clicked on the right and left at the same time.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie He says he is sometimes able to do it, so it does not seem like a physical mouse problem to me. Then again there is no information about the actual mouse being used, so you could be correct.

Comment: @ColinD You're right, and I missed that. Asker, could you clarify which mouse you're using? And whether Colin's hold-then-press trick works?

Answer (score 8):

The [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Page on Skyrim's controls](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Controls) even mentions this issue with mice like the Apple Magic Mouse:

> **Dual Cast**: Attack with both hands simultaneously. If the same spell is assigned to both hands and you have unlocked the appropriate Dual Casting perk, a more powerful version of the spell is cast. If your mouse doesn't support left click + right click--some don't--remap right click to an unused modifier key, for example the Applications Key (or on a Macintosh running bootcamp, the cmd key) and use that instead.

This way, you can Command+click to dual cast.

Alternatively, you can pick up a cheap USB mouse (~$10) and plug that in when playing Skyrim to get separate left- and right-click buttons that can be pressed simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is occurring because the current Apple Mouse can only click one button at a time, there isn't a split in the middle.

The simplest solution is to re-map your controls to perform the left hand function with a keyboard key. I personally use the 'V' key. Like that, you can use your shield/secondary weapon, and dual cast spells or dual wield weapons.

The method to do this is:

> Click Escape > Controls, then click "Left Hand". Press your desired key.

Done :)